# getch() returns \377! instead of reading character

Tags: xcode, curses, getchar, getch

I am using Xcode and using the C language trying to understand how to use the Getch function to start a project. I copied some code someone had written as an example that should work, however instead of the code waiting for me to enter a character, it returns one for me:

```
#include <midi_lib.h> <---------- this needs to be here for later
#include <curses.h>
int main() {
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE); /* I dont know if this is needed*/
  char c;
  puts("Enter a character\n");
  c = getch();
  printf("You just typed a %c! \n", c);
  getch();
}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter a character

You just typed a \377!
```

It works if i use Getchar(), but i dont want to have to press enter.

I'm really new to coding so it maybe something simple, but i have no idea....

LT

Comment: IIRC \377 == 255 decimal == -1 in 2s compliment == EOF

Comment: Check the manpage for getch() you may find it says something like ' In no-delay mode, if no input is waiting, the value ERR is returned.' In which case it's returning immediately with ERR.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't even initialize the Ncurses library with `initscr()`.

There really are a lot of things you are missing, so I recommend you to read the [Ncurses howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) that explains you everything from initializing (e.g. what that `keypad(stdscr, true)` is) to input and a lot more.

Here's an example that works:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    ch = getch();
    endwin();

    printf("The key pressed is %d\n", ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get you started

```
#include <midi_lib.h> <---------- this needs to be here for later
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    char c;

    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);  /* I dont know if this is needed*/

    puts("Enter a character\n");
    do {
        c = getch();   
    } while (c == (char)-1);

   printf("You just typed a %c! \n",c);
}
```

Note that getch() is constantly polling the keyboard for input, when there is
none, it will get -1 and retry until there is some in which case it will fall out of the while loop and continue.

This probably isn't how you should be coding this, but it does answer your question. The computer will act busy while it is constantly polling the keyboard.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
I have tried your code (and I now understand what you mean), but when I enter a character, I would expect it to fall out of the do while loop, however it doesn't and i dont understand why?